# Send/Receive data via USB between Vex Cortex and .net

Tags: c, vb.net, serial-port, usb

I'm coding in vb.net (I will accept answers in c# as I can approach this either way) and I need to send data to and receive data from a [Vex Cortex](http://www.vexrobotics.com/276-2194.html). It has a USB port on it which I will be connecting to a computer to send it data via a program.

I have researched this and the .net side seems fairly straightforward. Here is the code I currently have:

```
    Dim sensor As New SerialPort("COM1")

    sensor.BaudRate = 9600
    sensor.Parity = Parity.None
    sensor.StopBits = StopBits.One
    sensor.DataBits = 8

    sensor.ReadTimeout = 300
    sensor.WriteTimeout = 300

    sensor.Handshake = Handshake.None
    sensor.Open()
```

I was looking around and i found some steps to take to send data from the program, which is below:

```
    Dim byteOut(5) As Byte
    Dim byteIn(6) As Byte
    Dim Voltage, i As Integer
    Try
        byteOut(0) = &H2  '2 bytes in output message
        byteOut(1) = &H0  'should be 0 for NXT
        byteOut(2) = &H0  '&H0 = reply expected &H80 = no reply expected
        byteOut(3) = &HB  '$HB = read battery command
        sensor.Write(byteOut, 0, 4) '0 = offset into byteOut and 4 = number of bytes
        'now read the reply
        byteIn(0) = sensor.ReadByte ' number of bytes in message
        byteIn(1) = sensor.ReadByte ' should be 0 for NXT
        For i = 2 To 1 + byteIn(0) ' read rest of message
            byteIn(i) = sensor.ReadByte()
        Next
        Voltage = byteIn(5) + byteIn(6) * 256 ' the voltage has low byte in 5 and high in 6
        Console.Write(Voltage) 'display voltage
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

The example above is used to return battery data for an irrelevant device for this question. Basically I need to be able to read the data I send, and send data back to the computer, on the Vex Cortex.

The Cortex is coded in c and I'm using RobotC to compile and download the code to the Cortex. I can't figure out how to read the data for the life of me (example code said to do `Serial.begin(9600);` but this raises a compilation error in RobotC).

Can anyone assist me on how to read (and write back) data on the Cortex end of this transfer? I may need to ditch RobotC and I'm perfectly fine with that if a solution is proposed without it, so long as it's still c code.

Comment: This is code to communicate with a COM port not a USB port. Are you using a USB-Serial adapter?

Comment: I'm using a USB cord, double-male that goes straight into the cortex. By your comment I'm assuming that you need different code to communicate with a USB port vs. a COM port. My apologies as I'm very new to the hardware end of things. :\

Comment: Have you read this documentation? http://www.education.rec.ri.cmu.edu/fire/media/cortex_startup.pdf. To use it with ROBOTC you need to install a Prolific USB-to-Serial COM Port driver and configure a COM Port to access it on.

Comment: I'm not sure if my question was unclear, but getting the programs compiled and downloaded is not the issue. I already can do that. AFTER I download the program, I need to be able to plug the USB cable back into the cortex and into a (different) computer, and have a way to send data from the computer to the cortex, and have the cortex respond with data after it executes the command(s) sent initially from the computer. For example, send 0 to the cortex which it will then read and interpret as "forward", 1 as "backward", 2 as "left", 3 as "right", etc.

Comment: ^ Adding to this, my (main) problem is, as stated in the question, that I don't know how to write the code / take advantage of the (poorly, if at all documented) libraries for the cortex that will listen for input, and then respond by writing data back. I know it's possible because RobotC does this (writes data back and forth with the cortex) when it's debugging the code. I just need to hook into the USB on the cortex and use it to my advantage - no need to debug with robotc after it is deployed, so I don't need to reserve the USB cable usage for connecting to robotc. Hope that's more clear.

Comment: Your question talks about ditching RobotC - I don't think you can do without RobotC

Comment: Ditching RobotC was kind of an "if I have to that's fine, so long as I can." I don't really know what my options are at this point.